# Setting font to recyclerview item text has a delay

Tags: android, styles, material-design

I use `font-family` in my style like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    <font
        app:font="@font/montserrat_regular"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/montserrat_regular"
        android:fontWeight="400" />
    <font
        app:font="@font/montserrat_bold"
        app:fontWeight="700"
        android:font="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:fontWeight="700"/>
</font-family>
```

And in the Theme:

```
        <!-- font family -->
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/mobile_font</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/mobile_font</item>
```

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="model"
            type="main.dashboard.UserContactItem" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/material_size_96"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            style="@style/Caption"
            asyncText="@{model.title}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivProfile"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/material_size_8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

When the items appear in the screen of the app, at first, the textview is shown with default font of the Android, then after a second, the font is set to textview.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After lots of investigation, I found that the problem was with textAppearance which was set to textview with `style="@style/Caption"`

```
    <style name="Caption" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_smaller</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:letterSpacing">0</item>
    </style>
```

Inheriting from `parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"` was the problem. So removing it solved my problem!